# Drag div element with canvas to another

Tags: html, canvas, drag-and-drop

I'm having my first experience in developing html5 applications. My issue is to make room plan. In the top of the page I have elements to drag to the bottom map area (they are copied). In the map area I can move elements, but not copy.

I've built drag'n'drop with help of image elements. But now I want to use canvas for updating numbers on images. I want to use canvas text functions for updating images.

The problem is when I copy canvas element from the top, html inserts well, but it is not drawn in some reasons.

Please, watch code here http://jsfiddle.net/InsideZ/MuGnv/2/. **Code was written for Google Chrome**.

Comment: If you have external js resources add them via the "Add Resources" section on the left of the page.

Comment: No, I don't. JQuery is external, but I've checked it to include.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific the js/floorplan.js is not found. But if it is not required, then ignore me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

I made a few small tweaks here: http://jsfiddle.net/MuGnv/5/

Note the changes made to the drawImg function:

```
function drawImg(src, targetClass) {

    $(targetClass).each(function() {
        var ctx = $(this).get(0).getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = src;
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        };

    });
}
```

Anytime a drop event is handled, the images are drawn again. This was the missing component as the image was only being drawn once.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing but this.innerHTML & $(this).html() don't make sense a lot. Item html code existed before (inspect the area in my version), so the problem is not in styles.

Comment: @InsideZ You are most definitely correct. Note the updated I have made. The fiddle based upon your original seems to be working as you would expect.